# Formating a Samsung Laptop

Tags: windows-7, linux, windows-8, laptop

I have a Samsung Laptop with Windows 7 OS system installed on it.

Now the system don't start. It sticks on the loading screen. So I decided to format my laptop.

When I insert Win7 format disk to computer, and after the first screen, when I press the "Install now" button, the screen shows me:

> Starting Instalation

After a few minutes (20-30) it still shows the above message.

So I decided to use Win8, WinXP, winVista and all have failed to load the partition screen.

Then I used Ubuntu and Linux distros.

It loads the kernel and everything works. But I want Windows not Linux!

I tried to configure my BIOS settings and nothing showed me that there's an error with my hardware. What is the problem?

How can I format the laptop?

Comment: Could you be more specific on what "hardware error" your BIOS is encountering?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to completely start over and format your laptop's hard drive, you may want to try [GPARTED](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gparted/postdownload?source=dlp) the Gnome partition editor.  Burn it to a disc and boot to that.  Then use the application to format your hard drive.

Get rid of all the partitions so the drive is completely erased including any boot partitions.  Then try your windows installation disk again.  Windows should allow you to create the partition necessary for the installation or will do it automatically for you.